# What's the purpose of const swap() function?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

While implementing a custom `tuple` ([here)](https://gist.github.com/seiren-naru-shirayuri/d0493137d688eb91277d00e0ed48b9a2), I found there is a wired `swap()` function that takes `const` parameters ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/swap2)):

```c++
template< class... Types >
constexpr void swap( const std::tuple<Types...>& lhs,
                     const std::tuple<Types...>& rhs ) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

and a const-qualified `swap()` member function ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/swap)):

```c++
constexpr void swap( const tuple& other ) noexcept(/* see below */) const;
```

`const` means the object is read-only, but to swap two objects, it has to modify the objects, which violates the `const`-ness.

So, What's the purpose of const swap() function?

Comment: Since C++23, interesting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was introduced in the "zip" proposal [P2321](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html) originally described in "A Plan for C++23 Ranges" [P2214](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html).

> P2321
>
> - swap for const tuple and const pair. Once tuples of references are
>   made const-assignable, the default std::swap can be called for const
>   tuples of references. However, that triple-move swap does the wrong
>   thing:
>
>   ```
>   int i = 1, j = 2;
>   const auto t1 = std::tie(i), t2 = std::tie(j);
>
>   // If std::swap(t1, t2); called the default triple-move std::swap then
>   // this would do
>   auto tmp = std::move(t1);
>   t1 = std::move(t2);
>   t2 = std::move(tmp);
>
>   // i == 2, j == 2
>   ```
>
>   This paper therefore proposes adding overloads of swap for const
>   tuples and pairs to correctly perform element-wise swap.

P2214 explains why const assignability is needed for the implementation of `zip`. It stems from assignment operators not being ref qualified.

Comment: Great thanks! Looks like the const qualified swap is just a hack. To fix the root problem, we have to overhaul the copy/move assignment operators.

Comment: Is that because tmp would contain a reference to i?

Answer (score 5):

You have missed the footnote about when that overload is available:

> This overload participates in overload resolution only if `std::is_swappable_v<const Ti>` is `true` for all i from 0 to `sizeof...(Types)`.

If you have a type `const_swappable` such that `swap(const const_swappable &, const const_swappable &)` is sensible, then there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to swap `const std::tuple<const_swappable> &`.

Answer (score 4):

As an example, consider a pointer-like type, that can swap the values of the pointee without modifying the pointer:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int * x;
};

void swap(const foo& a, const foo& b){
    std::swap(*a.x,*b.x);
};

int main(){
    int a = 42;
    int b = 3;

    foo f1{&a};
    foo f2{&b};

    swap(f1,f2);

    std::cout << "foo is const swappable: " << std::is_swappable_v<const foo> << "\n";
    std::cout << *f1.x << "\n";
    std::cout << *f2.x << "\n";

}
```

And note from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/swap2):

> 2. The program is ill-formed if `(std::is_swappable_v<const Types> && ...)` is not `true`.

That is: You can only const swap the tuples if the types in the tuple can be const swapped.